# Redux request rejected although token is passed correctly

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, authorization

I have created a redux async thunk function in my slice file that calls an axios put request from my service file. My backend I am running with mongodb, mongoose, and express.js; The backend works perfectly when I try to update my information on postman. However, when I send the dispatch to call the update function from redux it says I am not authorized because I don't have a token but I am passing the token in the picture

Service JS file:

```js
   

// Update a practitioner profile
const updatePractitionerProfile = async (practitionerProfileId, token, data) => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    }

    const response = await axios.put(API_URL + practitionerProfileId, data, config)

    return response.data
}
```

Slice JS file:

```js
// Update a practitioner profile
export const updatePractitionerProfile = createAsyncThunk(
    "practitionerProfiles/update",
    async (id, data, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token
            return await practitionerProfileService.updatePractitionerProfile(
                id, token, data
            );
        } catch (error) {
            const message =
                (error.response &&
                    error.response.data &&
                    error.response.data.message) ||
                error.message ||
                error.toString();
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
        }
    }
);
```

```js
const initialState = {
    profile: {},
    practitionerProfiles:[],
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isLoading: false,
    message: "",
};


export const practitionerProfileSlice = createSlice({
    name: "practitionerProfile",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        reset: (state) => initialState,
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(updatePractitionerProfile.pending, (state) => {
                state.isLoading = true
            })
            .addCase(updatePractitionerProfile.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false
                state.isSuccess = true
                state.profile = action.payload
            })
            .addCase(updatePractitionerProfile.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false
                state.isError = true
                state.message = action.payload
            })
    }
});
```